# How do I make an impact in a new job where I feel the team is not supportive and pulling me back?

Tags: career-development, team, onboarding

I have completed 3 months in a new company. I have over 9 years experience some of them as a lead but I joined here as an individual contributor.
**I am finding it difficult to make an impact despite trying very hard.
Two examples:**

1. I was given transition for a particular application and I spent considerable time understanding it. After almost 2 months I was told that this application won't be transitioned after all, so basically I almost wasted 2 months learning all about it.
2. The team needs a lot of automation to streamline some routine work. I took the initiative and pushed very hard to get some of them done. But apparently other people in the team were assigned or supposed to do it and although they have not made much progress on it, I still need to keep waiting on them asking them where they are, and following up meaninglessly.

When I got something done that helps the team and I got it done in good time, why can't I just showcase my work?
My manager is also kind of old school and clearly does not want to be pulled into any conflict.

I have tried to befriend my colleagues by helping them when I can. Overall i get a feeling that they act superior to me probably because I have a lot of experience and yet working at the same level as them

I would appreciate any advice around:

1. I have completed some work that was pending for long. It was just "assigned' to someone and even after reaching out multiple times I did not get any tangible response on how much of the work was actually done. Can I go ahead and showcase my work to the team?
2. I see people questioning my abilities and experience, not direct but subtly. Example : jobs get tougher over 10 yrs etc.

Answer (score 1):

My reading of your point no. 1 is that you took on a task that has been pending for a while, without any direction to do so, and without telling anyone that you had done so. As a result, it was eventually assigned to another person, who is presumably unaware that you were already working on (completed?) said problem.

I would probably also be pretty confused if the new guy was asking me about a problem that I just got assigned, that in my mind has nothing to do with him. You should absolutely talk to your manager if you feel that you have lots of open time that could be filled with assignments. Filling your own plate is good, but it doesn't help you out at all if no one knows that you're doing the work.

If you want to showcase your work, you should do work that your manager is aware that you're doing, and showcase that you can tackle what you're given. It's no use to do work that no one will see, because you weren't supposed to do it in the first place, that's simply a waste of time.

As far as people questioning your experience, its just noise. Don't let it get to you. Continue working on *your assignments* and helping out the team when needed. Others will soon catch on that you are an experienced teammate if they are given the opportunity to see your performance on appropriately completed assignments.

Answer (score -1):

Wasting time on something that never makes it into production is part of the profession. It's frustrating but usually unavoidable. Get used to it.

Re working with other people: TALK TO YOUR MANAGER about what you can tackle that needs to be done, how to approach it, and how to handle any setbacks.

Re people questioning you: That's a problem we can't fix for you. Either they are and you need to figure out how to work with them more effectively, or they aren't and you need to learn how to not take their comments so personally. Again, TALK TO YOUR MANAGER about resolving any conflicts; that's what manglement is there for.